# How to prove orthogonal group is compact with induction topology?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

I would like to prove that $O(n,R)$ is a compact set. 
Can I just view $O(n,R)$ as a subset of $R^{n*n}$ and prove it is compact by proving it is bounded and closed?

Comment: Yes, you certainly can.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Oh, so it’s just a simple verification！

Comment: @MingweiZhang It is a verification. That it is simple, you will know only after doing it, right?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Yeah, thank you!

Comment: For completeness, once you are done with your argument, post an answer below and we can verify and check it is ok.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I’m to prove it’s bounded by using the fact that every number is bounded by 1. And it’s closed because limit of orthogonal matrix sequence is still orthogonal by continuity of matrix multiplication.

Comment: Yes, that is fine. Post it as an answer, then close the question by accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

OK.

I’m to prove it’s bounded by using the fact that every number is bounded by 1.

And it’s closed because limit of orthogonal matrix sequence is still orthogonal by continuity of matrix multiplication.